# How to create a second R shiny dropdown list whose options depend on a first dropdown list selection

Tags: r, shiny

Imagine two vectors

```
A <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
B <- c("b", "d", "e", "f")
```

Now imagine an R Shiny UI with two drop-down menus

- Main_selection
- Sub_selection

The options of Main Selection should be A and B

**How can the options of Sub_Selection be changed in response to the user's selection of A or B in the Main_Selection?**

i.e. Sub Selection will present a choice of

- a
- b
- c
- d

iff Main Selection == A, and

- b
- d
- e
- f

iff Main Selection == B

Many thanks,

Jon