# R-Shiny two selectInput variables with partial dependency

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am new to Shiny and I did my search on two relavant questions:

- [How to create a second R shiny dropdown list whose options depend on a first dropdown list selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259211/how-to-create-a-second-r-shiny-dropdown-list-whose-options-depend-on-a-first-dro?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [R-Shiny using Reactive renderUI value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053493/r-shiny-using-reactive-renderui-value)

Both examples involved one variable nested within another variable. With selection of A, you have second level of options 1, 2 and 3. With selection of B, you have options 4, 5 and 6. My problem is similar yet different. I am trying to create two `selectInput` menus beased on two variables (Y: A, B, C and X: D, E, F) but they are partially dependent with no hierarchy. I use the table below to illustrate:

```
x\y A   B   C
D   v   v   
E   v   v   
F       v   v
```

So what I want is when I:

- choose A from the first dropdown, only D and E show up in the second menu;
- choose B from the first dropdown, D, E and F show up in the second menu;
- choose C from the first dropdown, only F shows up in the second menu

and vice versa

- choose D from the second dropdown, only A and B show up in the first menu;
- choose E from the second dropdown, only A and B show up in the first menu;
- choose F from the second dropdown, only B and C show up in the first menu.

What will be the best way to approach this? I created a toy example to illustrate what I want to achieve:

```
library(lattice)
library(shiny)
y=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
    "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
    "B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C")
x=c("D","D","D","D","D","E","E","E","E","E",
    "D","D","D","D","D","E","E","E","E","E",
    "F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F")
mean.y=c(10.75,10.97,10.62,10.15,10.58,10.41,10.22,10.59,10.05,10.24,
         10.84,10.54,10.38,10.06,10.70,10.14,10.80,10.99,10.43,10.59,
         10.66,10.55,10.93,10.71,10.90,10.28,10.62,10.76,10.63,10.86)   
mean.x=c(5.19,5.22,5.99,5.05,5.38,5.72,5.14,5.22,5.78,5.05,
         5.94,5.39,5.71,5.45,5.66,5.61,5.46,5.24,5.79,5.67,
         5.00,5.30,5.44,5.27,5.60,5.20,5.94,5.67,5.06,5.25)
dat=as.data.frame(cbind(y,x,mean.y,mean.x))
X=as.list(unique(as.character(dat$x)))
Y=as.list(unique(as.character(dat$y)))
ui=fluidPage(
  titlePanel("X vs. Y Scatter Plots"),
  uiOutput("x"),
  uiOutput("y"),
  plotOutput(outputId="scatter")
)
server=function(input,output){
  output$x=renderUI({
    selectInput("x","X",x)
  })
  output$y=renderUI({
    selectInput("y","Y",y)
  })
  output$scatter=renderPlot({
    dat=subset(dat,x==input$x & y==input$y)
    xyplot(dat$mean.y~dat$mean.x)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

**Edited:**
BTW, I would like to retrive those levels from the data instead of calling the level in the code since I will have several files that will be analyzed with different dependency.

Thank you all very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `isolate` and `updateSelectInput`
Try

```
   library(shiny)
y=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
    "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
    "B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C")
x=c("D","D","D","D","D","E","E","E","E","E",
    "D","D","D","D","D","E","E","E","E","E",
    "F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F")
dd=data.frame(x,y,stringsAsFactors = F)

ui=fluidPage(
  titlePanel("X vs. Y Scatter Plots"),
  selectInput("x","X",c("",unique(dd$x))),
  selectInput("y","Y",c("",unique(dd$y)))
)
server=function(input,output,session){
  observeEvent(input$x,{
    if(input$x==""){
      updateSelectInput(session,"y",choices = c("",unique(dd$y))) 
    }else{
    updateSelectInput(session,"y",choices = unique(dd$y[dd$x==input$x]),selected = isolate(input$y))
    }
      })

  observeEvent(input$y,{
    if(input$y==""){
      updateSelectInput(session,"x",choices = c("",unique(dd$x))) 
    }else{
    updateSelectInput(session,"x",choices = unique(dd$x[dd$y==input$y]),selected = isolate(input$x))
    }
  } )
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Update

Try add "*" as choises to reset ( any time "*" chiosed)

```
ui=fluidPage(
  titlePanel("X vs. Y Scatter Plots"),
  selectInput("x","X",c("_",unique(dd$x))),
  selectInput("y","Y",c("_",unique(dd$y)))
)
server=function(input,output,session){
  observeEvent(input$x,{
    if(input$x=="_"){
      updateSelectInput(session,"y",choices = c("_",unique(dd$y))) 
    }else{
      updateSelectInput(session,"y",choices = c("_",unique(dd$y[dd$x==input$x])),selected = isolate(input$y))
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$y,{
    if(input$y=="_"){
      updateSelectInput(session,"x",choices = c("_",unique(dd$x))) 
    }else{
      updateSelectInput(session,"x",choices = c("_",unique(dd$x[dd$y==input$y])),selected = isolate(input$x))
    }
  } )
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: One further question I have is that is it possible to have blank current values for both dropdowns with all three options and as soon as the first one is chosen then the dependency appears? Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you very much again! It works well but once the first output was generated, then the selection is fixed and cannot be reset. I have been reading some reset references but haven't had much success yet. I will keep trying. Very appreciate your help!